# Fetch last indexed document from every index with matching pattern

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple indexes let's say

```
test-node1
test-node2
test-node3
test-node4
test-node5
test-node6
```

Now i want to fetch latest indexed document from every index (pattern would be **test-***) in one query.
How do i do that?

Result will contain total 6  documents in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have a field called "timestamp" where you're storing the indexing time, you can run the following

```
GET test-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_index": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      }, 
      "aggs": {
        "last_index": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{
              "timestamp": {"order": "desc"}
            }]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```